# hdf5 and ndarray append / time-efficient approach for large data-sets

Tags: python, performance, numpy, hdf5

**Background**

I have a k n-dimensional time-series, each represented as m x (n+1) array holding float values (n columns plus one that represents the date).

*Example:*

k (around 4 million) time-series that look like

```
20100101    0.12    0.34    0.45    ...
20100105    0.45    0.43    0.21    ...
...         ...     ...     ...
```

Each day, I want to add for a subset of the data sets (< k) an additional row. All datasets are stored in groups in *one* hd5f file.

**Question**

What is the most time-efficient approach to append the rows to the data sets?

Input is a CSV file that looks like

```
key1, key2, key3, key4, date, value1, value2, ...
```

whereby date is unique for the particular file and could be ignored. I have around 4 million data sets. The issue is that I have to look-up the key, get the complete numpy array, resize the array, add the row and store the array again. The total size of the hd5f file is around 100 GB. Any idea how to speed this up? 
I think we can agree that using SQLite or something similar doesn't work - as soon as I have all the data, an average data set will have over 1 million elements times 4 million data sets.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using h5py? It works with NumPy arrays and you should just be able to append the data you want without reading the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin)?  It's a hierarchical database built on top of the HDF5 library.

It has several array types, but the "table" type sounds like it would work for your data format.  It's basically an on-disk version of a NumPy record array, where each column can be a unique data type.  Tables have an append method that can easily add additional rows.

As far as loading the data from CSV files, numpy.loadtxt is quite fast.  It will load the file into memory as a NumPy record array.

Comment: I looked at PyTables but the downsize is that it isn't Py3 compatible (yet). Furthermore, you add another layer to your system and break compatibility with hdf5. Besides that, I wrote my own indexing engine that works very well - PyTables does not support indexing in the BSD version. But thanks for the tip.