# Speeding up python code with cython

Tags: python, optimization, cython

I have a function which just basically makes lots of calls to a simple defined hash function and tests to see when it finds a duplicate.  I need to do lots of simulations with it so would like it to be as fast as possible.  I am attempting to use cython to do this. The cython code is currently called with a normal python list of integers with values in the range 0 to m^2.

```
import math, random
cdef int a,b,c,d,m,pos,value, cyclelimit, nohashcalls   
def h3(int a,int b,int c,int d, int m,int x):
    return (a*x**2 + b*x+c) %m    
def floyd(inputx):
    dupefound, nohashcalls = (0,0)
    m = len(inputx)
    loops = int(m*math.log(m))
    for loopno in xrange(loops):
        if (dupefound == 1):
            break
        a = random.randrange(m)
        b = random.randrange(m)
        c = random.randrange(m)
        d = random.randrange(m)
        pos = random.randrange(m)
        value = inputx[pos]
        listofpos = [0] * m
        listofpos[pos] = 1
        setofvalues = set([value])
        cyclelimit = int(math.sqrt(m))
        for j in xrange(cyclelimit):
            pos = h3(a,b, c,d, m, inputx[pos])
            nohashcalls += 1    
            if (inputx[pos] in setofvalues):
                if (listofpos[pos]==1):
                    dupefound = 0
                else:
                    dupefound = 1
                    print "Duplicate found at position", pos, " and value", inputx[pos]
                break
            listofpos[pos] = 1
            setofvalues.add(inputx[pos])
    return dupefound, nohashcalls
```

How can I convert inputx and listofpos to use C type arrays and to access the arrays at C speed?  Are there any other speed ups I can use?  Can setofvalues be sped up?

So that there is something to compare against, 50 calls to floyd() with m = 5000 currently takes around 30 seconds on my computer.

Update: Example code  snippet to show how floyd is called.

```
m = 5000
inputx = random.sample(xrange(m**2), m)
(dupefound, nohashcalls) = edcython.floyd(inputx)
```

Comment: Have you thought of adding in a mechanism to memorize past results? I see a potential for overlapping calls to the `hash` method and this could speed up your algorithm considerably at the sacrifice of memory space.

Comment: Do you mean storing results of h3?  The function stops as soon as it finds a duplicate so this doesn't seem to help. I suspect the main speedup would come from using C type arrays but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What is the exact input into `floyd`? I'm assuming just a `list` of integers?

Comment: Here is an example. m= 5000 . inputx = random.sample(xrange(m**2), m) . (dupefound, nohashcalls) = edcython.floyd(inputx) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, it seems that you must type the variables *inside* the function. [A good example of it is here.](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/early_binding_for_speed.html)

Second, `cython -a`, for "annotate", gives you a really excellent break down of the code generated by the cython compiler and a color-coded indication of how dirty (read: python api heavy) it is. This output is really essential when trying to optimize anything.

Third, the now famous page on [working with Numpy](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) explains how to get fast, C-style access to the Numpy array data. Unforunately it's verbose and annoying. We're in luck however, because  more recent Cython provides [Typed Memory Views](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), which are both easy to use and *awesome*. Read that entire page before you try to do anything else.

After ten minutes or so I came up with this:

```
# cython: infer_types=True

# Use the C math library to avoid Python overhead.
from libc cimport math
# For boundscheck below.
import cython
# We're lazy so we'll let Numpy handle our array memory management.
import numpy as np
# You would normally also import the Numpy pxd to get faster access to the Numpy
# API, but it requires some fancier compilation options so I'll leave it out for
# this demo.
# cimport numpy as np

import random

# This is a small function that doesn't need to be exposed to Python at all. Use
# `cdef` instead of `def` and inline it.
cdef inline int h3(int a,int b,int c,int d, int m,int x):
    return (a*x**2 + b*x+c) % m

# If we want to live fast and dangerously, we tell cython not to check our array
# indices for IndexErrors. This means we CAN overrun our array and crash the
# program or screw up our stack. Use with caution. Profiling suggests that we
# aren't gaining anything in this case so I leave it on for safety.
# @cython.boundscheck(False)
# `cpdef` so that calling this function from another Cython (or C) function can
# skip the Python function call overhead, while still allowing us to use it from
# Python.
cpdef floyd(int[:] inputx):
    # Type the variables in the scope of the function.
    cdef int a,b,c,d, value, cyclelimit
    cdef unsigned int dupefound = 0
    cdef unsigned int nohashcalls = 0
    cdef unsigned int loopno, pos, j

    # `m` has type int because inputx is already a Cython memory view and
    # `infer-types` is on.
    m = inputx.shape[0]

    cdef unsigned int loops = int(m*math.log(m))

    # Again using the memory view, but letting Numpy allocate an array of zeros.
    cdef int[:] listofpos = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.int32)

    # Keep this random sampling out of the loop
    cdef int[:, :] randoms = np.random.randint(0, m, (loops, 5)).astype(np.int32)

    for loopno in range(loops):
        if (dupefound == 1):
            break

        # From our precomputed array
        a = randoms[loopno, 0]
        b = randoms[loopno, 1]
        c = randoms[loopno, 2]
        d = randoms[loopno, 3]
        pos = randoms[loopno, 4]

        value = inputx[pos]

        # Unforunately, Memory View does not support "vectorized" operations
        # like standard Numpy arrays. Otherwise we'd use listofpos *= 0 here.
        for j in range(m):
            listofpos[j] = 0

        listofpos[pos] = 1
        setofvalues = set((value,))
        cyclelimit = int(math.sqrt(m))
        for j in range(cyclelimit):
            pos = h3(a, b, c, d, m, inputx[pos])
            nohashcalls += 1
            if (inputx[pos] in setofvalues):
                if (listofpos[pos]==1):
                    dupefound = 0
                else:
                    dupefound = 1
                    print "Duplicate found at position", pos, " and value", inputx[pos]
                break
            listofpos[pos] = 1
            setofvalues.add(inputx[pos])
    return dupefound, nohashcalls
```

There are no tricks here that aren't explained on [docs.cython.org](http://docs.cython.org), which is where I learned them myself, but helps to see it all come together.

The most important changes to your original code are in the comments, but they all amount to giving Cython hints about how to generate code that doesn't use the Python API.

As an aside: I really don't know why `infer_types` is not on by default. It lets the compiler
implicitly use C types instead of Python types where possible, meaning less work for you.

If you run `cython -a` on this, you'll see that the only lines that call into Python are your calls to random.sample, and building or adding to a Python set().

On my machine, your original code runs in 2.1 seconds. My version runs in 0.6 seconds.

<strike>The next step is to get random.sample out of that loop, but I'll leave that to you.</strike>

I have edited my answer to demonstrate how to precompute the rand samples. This brings the time down to **0.4 seconds**.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. The a, b,c,d variables need to be resampled in each iteration of the for loop so can't be precomputed but maybe C's rand() could be used instead.

Comment: Yes, but `m` is fixed and you know that you need exactly `loops` samples of each of them. I'd probably use `numpy.random.randint(0, m, size=loops)` and then just index into that.

Comment: Some benchmarking also indicated that `cython.boundscheck(False)` wasn't speeding anything up so I commented it out for safety's sake. Under *normal* circumstances you *do* want boundscheck. Only turn it off if after your code is finished and tested and even then, only if it has a real impact when benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks. I have also tried your code in cython 0.15 but it seems it doesn't understand the [:] notation which seems to be new in 0.16.

Comment: Yes, they are a relatively new feature I think. They are preferred because they only require that the incoming data implements buffers as specified in PEP 3118, but if you're working solely with numpy arrays you can just use the numpy api and be done with it. `cdef int[:] foo = ...` becomes `cdef np.ndarray(int, ndim=1) foo = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use this particular hashing algorithm?  Why not use the built-in hashing algorithm for dicts?  For example:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(inputx)
dupes = [k for k, v in cnt.iteritems() if v > 1]
```

Comment: I do. I will be using a number of home grown hash functions in fact.